# How do I start and stop thread using jButton in JInternalFrame

Tags: multithreading, using, jinternalframe

StopWatch(JInternalFrame) code for Starting the Thread from (jButton1)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
          while(true)
          {
              try
              {
                  for(int hour=0;hour<24;hour++)
                  {
                      for(int minutes=0;minutes<60;minutes++)
                      {
                          for(int seconds=0;seconds<60;seconds++)
                          {
                              jLabel2.setText(hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
                              Thread.sleep(1000);
                          }
                      }

                  }
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
              }
          }
      }
    }.start();
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Code for stopping Thread from (jButton2)

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   Thread.currentThread().stop(); // Not Working
```

}

So is there any way to stop and resume the same thread running onto JInternalFrame.